# ActivityManager.MemoryInfo and /proc/meminfo file have different values

Tags: android, linux, performance, memory, performance-testing

I am trying to find total available memory on the device and overall memory usage of a device.

I found two ways to do it.

1) Read statistics from /proc/meminfo file
2) Use Android's ActivityManger.MemoryInfo API

Both this ways returns different values.

Comment: What values return different values ? probably may be due to the fact that:
- execute the operation in two different time instants
- units of measurement
Surely between the two the most reliable, is /proc/meminfo

Answer (score 1):

This is ironical but the implementation of `ActivityManger.MemoryInfo.availMem` includes both **MemFree** and **Cached** from `/proc/meminfo`. This can be traced back to the native implementation of `Android.os.Process.getFreeMemory()` in [android_util_Process.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/jni/android_util_Process.cpp)

```
`static jlong android_os_Process_getFreeMemory(JNIEnv* env, jobject clazz)
{
    static const char* const sums[] = { "MemFree:", "Cached:", NULL };
    static const size_t sumsLen[] = { strlen("MemFree:"), strlen("Cached:"), 0 };
    return getFreeMemoryImpl(sums, sumsLen, 2);
}`
```